# std::shuffle всегда одинаковый результат

Tags: c++

Всем привет, при запуске программы shuffle всегда тусует вектор одинаково, не понимаю, что не так

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> backgroundSongs = {
            "../music/Sound_04669.mp3",
            "../music/Sound_11084.mp3",
            "../music/Sound_17211.mp3"
    };

    //std::random_device rd;
    //std::default_random_engine rng(rd());

    shuffle(backgroundSongs.begin(), backgroundSongs.end(), std::mt19937(std::random_device()()));

    for (const auto& song : backgroundSongs)
        cout << song << " ";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Всегда одна последовательность `../music/Sound_17211.mp3 ../music/Sound_11084.mp3 ../music/Sound_04669.mp3`

Comment: Проверьте при разных запусках, что дает `std::random_device()()` в вашей системе. Разные значения или нет?

Comment: @Harry, разные, но всегда одни и те же на конкретной "итерации" использования, я в ответе указал, в чём проблема

Comment: *разные, но всегда одни и те же на конкретной "итерации" использования* :) Это и есть - одинаковые (одинаковая последовательность значений). Вот и ответ - плохая реализация `random_device`, которая на самом деле не совсем random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в реализации g++ в текущей (по-моему, предпоследней) версии mingw
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680805/why-is-random-library-producing-the-same-results-every-time-when-using-stdun

Решение проблемы следующее:

```
vector<string> backgroundSongs = {
            "../music/Sound_04669.mp3",
            "../music/Sound_11084.mp3",
            "../music/Sound_17211.mp3"
    };
default_random_engine randEngine(static_cast<uint32_t>(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()));
shuffle(backgroundSongs .begin(), backgroundSongs .end(), randEngine);
```

Comment: Или обновите компилятор. В новом mingw это починено.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, тоже верно, но там вроде самый новый только 64 битный, ну по крайней мере так на sourceforge при скачивании

Comment: Есть много разных сборок MinGW. Обычный MinGW - не очень, MinGW-w64 лучше. Больше всего мне нравится сборки с https://www.msys2.org/ и https://winlibs.com/ . Проверил в MSYS2 - там есть GCC 10.3 и 64-, и 32-битный (на котором все работает как надо). *"только 64 битный"* А что не так с 64 битами?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, проект большой очень, сидеть щас менять либы на 64 битные и тд не очень хочется уже, но вообще, кнш, надо бы на самое новое всё перейти)

Comment: Ну вот можете взять 32-битный GCC из MSYS2, в котором это пофикшено. А что с либами? В смысле собирать их по 64 бита лениво? Они могут быть в пакетном менеджере уже собранные.